# Windows Client application on USB stick with write protection

Tags: c#, windows, usb-flash-drive, client-applications

I need one or more approaches to realize the following scenarion:

Let's say we have a windows application (a journal) where journal entries are serialized as XML.

The application is on a usb stick and also the XML file.

The main problem is: no one should be able to write/delete the usb stick except the application itself.

I've read about usb sticks with mechanical or software write lock. But this would also disallow the application to write?!

I'm happy about any approaches.

p.s. It would be a .NET 3.5 WPF Application. But I think that doesn't matter the problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Applications run with the privileges of the user.  If the application can do it, the user can do it.

Comment: That's right. My question focuses more on approaches without using filesystem permissions. One of my ideas was a sql compact database instead of a XML file in compination with a hardware lock on the usb stick. But at the moment I can't try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea would be two use 2 partitions. One readonly partition (there should be tools out there that can create cdfs partitions) with your application on it and another secured with a password only known by your App. Possibly Truecrypt or some other partition encryption tools have the needed feature.

Comment: After some research the problems got more and more. I would need special usb sticks with named controllers which have a mass production tool. Other solutions are U3 hardware with the sandisk launchpad. But U3 is no longer supported by sandisk. So creating a cdfs partition on a common usb stick is not that simple. What works is a portable truecrypt mounting an encrypted container from C#.